# STM32F4 I2C Driver Issue

Tags: c, embedded, driver, i2c, stm32f4discovery

```
/**************************************************************************************************************************************
 * @brief  :    Function writes an 8-bit data to sensor's register
 *
 * @param1 :    I2C HandleTypedef structure that handles the I2C slave device
 * @param2 :    Slave device's address
 * @param3 :    The base register address in order to be write.
 * @param4 :    The 8-bit data that desired to be written
 *
 * @return :    Returns PROCESS_OK which is defined as 1
 *      Returns PROCESS_FAIL which is defined as 0 and calls Error_Writing function
 **************************************************************************************************************************************/
process_stat_t Sensor_WriteByte_ToReg(I2C_HandleTypeDef *p_hi2c, uint8_t device_addr, uint8_t base_reg_addr, uint8_t data)
{

    if(HAL_OK == HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(p_hi2c, device_addr, base_reg_addr, 1, &data, 1, I2C_TIMEOUT))
    {
        return PROCESS_OK;
    }
    else
    {
        Error_Writing(); // red led blinks 3 times
        return PROCESS_FAIL;
    }

}
```

This is a generic I2C function that I wrote. But always returns PROCESS_FAIL. Is there anyone see something wrong and can you explain it?

Thanks..

This is a generic I2C function that I wrote. But always returns PROCESS_FAIL. Is there anyone see something wrong and can you explain it?

Comment: Well you've not give us much to go on here. A common mistake is forgetting to shift the device address left by one bit, which is what the HAL function expects. Maybe you've done it elsewhere, we can't tell.

Comment: yes, I shifted device_addr left once. Whatelse can be the problem? Is there anything wrong just in this function?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong in this particular function. Capture the return value from the HAL function and see what it is, it might tell you something.

Comment: What is the value of I2C_TIMEOUT ?  For testing purposes, can this be increased?  The call looks ok to me in all honesty.

Comment: HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c2, BMP280_DEVICE_ADDR0, 5, 1000) This function returns HAL_ERROR but I dont know why. (BMP280_DEVICE_ADDR0 = 0xEC). I cant understan if the problem is hw related or sw related

Comment: You can use `HAL_I2C_GetError()` to find the cause of the error.

Comment: @doguu please post your actual code and not wrappers. If there is something wrong with your function, it must be something *inside* it. Please post full implementations of all I2C functions you've written. Show how you setup and configure I2C starting with its clock and all the config bits.